# GeoServer returns 405: Method Not found during POST method

Tags: rest, asp.net-core-1.0, geoserver

I am trying to implement Get,Post,Put and Delete operation on the layers using GeoServer Rest.

I am able to implement Get,Put and Delete method successfully.

But when i am trying to implement Post method on the layer, GeoServer returns status code: 405 i.e. Method Not Found.

> Here is my code:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostLayer(string layerName)
    {
        var authValue = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("admin:geoserver")));
        try
        {
            var client = new HttpClient()
            {
                DefaultRequestHeaders = { Authorization = authValue }
            };
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080");
            var stringContent = new StringContent(@"C:\Users\i2vsys\Desktop\test.kml");

            var response = await client.PostAsync($"/geoserver/rest/layers/{layerName}",stringContent);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var stringResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return Ok(stringResponse);
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

But according to GeoServer api documentation it has POST method. So, problem is definitely from my side and i am unable to find that. I have also seen others question but those solution didn't work for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I look at the [layers documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/api/#/1.0.0/layers.yaml) I see no reference to POST requests. What did you hope that a POST would do?

To create a new layer you first [create a new DataStore](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/workspaces.html#uploading-a-shapefile) as described in the examples. Using some thing like:

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPUT -H "Content-type: application/zip"
  --data-binary @roads.zip http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/acme/datastores/roads/file.shp
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. But how can i post a layer to the geoserver using REST Api.

Comment: You POST a new feature type which 
forms the new layer for you. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12970/create-a-layer-in-geoserver-using-rest